# Why won't rendering work in blender?

Tags: export, video

I am trying to export a super simple animation, and it always outputs a blank screen for the video.

[image]

I have looked at all the question on this topic, and they don't seem to help me.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is my file:

Comment: share your file so is easier to see what's going on

Comment: Ok @emir I will share my file.